# Setting up a regular payment schedule such as for a Direct Debit

Tags: date

I have been searching for some time now for a way to set up a spreadsheet to automatically input the time and date and the amount of the direct debit without me having to type this in every month.
I use this to track utility bills etc.

I could not find anything ready made so thought that this may be of use to others.

1. I created a new sheet called "Dates"
2. Opened up the scrip editor and used the following script

   function myFunction() {
   var sheetname = "Dates";//Sheet where you want to put the date`enter
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
   // You could use now Date(); on its own but it will not look nice.
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "dd/MM/yyyy");
   //var endDate = date;
   sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue(date); //Gets the last row which had value, and
   goes to the next empty row to put new values.
   }

This basically puts the current date in cell A1 of Dates and then follows on each time the script is run to A2, A3 etc.

3. On the sheet that contains all of the data I then used a cell formula to link the cell I wanted the date in to "Data A1" - (=Dates!A1)
4. I then copied the formula to the cells below where subsequent monthly dates needed to be input.
5. Now it was time to set the trigger for the script. As the Direct debit comes out on the 1st of the month it was easy to create a trigger that was time driven, monthly, 1st of each month
6. So the date will now populate automatically but what about the payment? A simple formula in the cell to the right of the date is as follows:
   =IF(B34<>"",$C$28,"").
   B34 is the cell that contains the date of the payment. If it is blank then cell C34 remains blank. If B34 contains any text then the contents of C28 are displayed. Cell C28 just has the amount of the regular payment. This formula was then copied to the cells below to match the number of rows that have the "dates"

So in conclusion, the regular payments now only appear when the specific due date has been reached and allows me to keep a running total of payments made along with a running balance

This is my first ever post and I apologise in advance if this has all been covered before and my approach in anyway appears to be the work of a dumb novice.

Comment: Please specify  which program you use as there are large numbers of spredsheet apps.

Comment: I use Google Sheets. Thanks for the question